# UnexpectedCharacters Error when parsing for roman numeral using lark parser (ebnf grammar)

Tags: python, parsing, ebnf, lark-parser

i'm using the follow grammar in lark-parser to parse alphabets and roman numerals. The grammar is as follows:

```
DIGIT: "0".."9"
INT: DIGIT+
_L_PAREN: "("
_R_PAREN: ")"
LCASE_LETTER: "a".."z"
ROMAN_NUMERALS: "viii" | "vii" | "iii" | "ii" | "ix" | "vi" | "iv" | "v" | "i" | "x"


?start: qns_num qns_alphabet  qns_part
qns_num: INT?
qns_alphabet: _L_PAREN LCASE_LETTER _R_PAREN | LCASE_LETTER _R_PAREN | LCASE_LETTER?
qns_part: _L_PAREN ROMAN_NUMERALS _R_PAREN | ROMAN_NUMERALS _R_PAREN | ROMAN_NUMERALS?
```

When i use this rule and parse the follow text, i get an exception:

```
# lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal defined for 'i' at line 1 col 5
# 10i)i)
#     ^
result = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr').parse("10i)i)")
```

For the life of me, i can't think of why this throws an exception. But this is fine:

```
result = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr').parse("10(i)(i)")  # no error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason this happens, is because both rules can be empty, which
>   causes the lexer to always jump over one of them in order to match the
>   terminal with the higher priority.
>
> With one rule empty and the second one matched, the parser expects an
>   EOF, not more input. The introduction of ( forces the rule to not be
>   empty.
>
> So, changing the priority on LCASE_LETTER won't help. But not allowing
>   the first rule to be empty will.
>
> The Earley algorithm will know how to resolve this ambiguity
>   automatically.

I asked the same question in `lark-parser` github page. Answer from [there](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/456).